# used jQuery to make my div expand with new information but it overlaps other information on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used J Query to make my div expand with new information but it overlaps other information on the page, can any one help resolve this issue?
I have only coded the first div to get it working before i do the rest.

Here is the fiddle for my code:
     http://jsfiddle.net/G59nH/

HTML:

```
<div class="contentBox2">
    <div class="servicesBox">
        <p>
            <b><u>Personal Breakthrough Sessions</u></b>
            <br>
            <i>“The secret of change is to focus all of your Energy, not on fighting the old, but on building the new.”</i>
            <br>
            <b>
                Socrates  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    

                <a id="clickme" href="#"><u>Read more</u></a><br />
                <div id="PBScontent" class="commenthidden">
                    You know when you are ready to breakthrough what has been holding you back to be and do something more. A Breakthrough Session is one full day or 2 half days (within 2 days) where Louise supports you through identifying what has been limiting you and then by using the tools from Strategic Intervention, NLP, Time Line Therapy and Hypnosis training, helps you break down the barriers and create new options to start you on a journey to achieve what you want. Louise will work with you to devise a plan, and making you accountable by requesting that some immediate action is taken, as accountability is put in place. In addition will arrange follow – up sessions to determine how you are progressing, holding the client accountable for planned actions. A worthwhile investment to lasting change and success in all areas of your life.
                </div>
            </b> 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="servicesBox">
        <p>
            <b><u>Relationship and Family Coaching</u></b>
            <br>
            <i>“A real decision is measured by the fact that you've taken a new action. If there's no action, you've haven't truly decided"</i>
            <br>
            <b>
                Tony Robbins &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <u>Read more</u>
            </b>
        </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="servicesBox">
        <p>
            <b><u>Coaching Children through Separation</u></b>
            <br>
            <i>"Overcome that notion that you must be regular. It robs you of the chance to be extra-ordinary."</i>
            <br>
            <b>
                Uta Hagen &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<u>Read more</u>
            </b>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="servicesBox">
        <p>
            <b><u>Well being Coach and Massage</u></b>
            <br>
            <i>"Modern medicine, for all its advances, knows less that 10% of what your body knows instinctively."
            ”</i>
            <br>
            <b>
                Deepak Chopra&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <u>Read more</u>
            </b>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="servicesBox">
        <p>
            <b><u>What i do!</u></b>
            <br>
            <i>I am a professional in Strategic Interventionist and Coaching, Master NLP/ Time Line Therapy and Hypnosis Practitioner and Therapeutic Massage Practitioner.</i>
            <br>
            <b>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <u>Read more</u>
            </b>
        </p>    
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#debug {
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
}
.commenthidden {
    display:none
}
.commentshown {
    display:inline
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $("#PBScontent").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

Comment: what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: expecting it to look like the div has expanded and the rest of the div's will just move down.. or if anyone has any better ideas it would be good to hear them.@czuroski

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/YLGNM/

Comment: So it is! hmm.. must be something to do with the other div's, as when i run it in any browser the content overlaps the rest of the div's on the page and they do not move. @Will

Comment: Consider making a fiddle with all of your actual code and editing your question.

Comment: How do i make a fiddle? @Will

Answer (score 1):

Try `display:block`, not `display:inline`.

Comment: display: block does not make any difference @user3303064

Comment: And if you remove your position:absolute, as well ?

Comment: Tried that, still the same. @Adosi

Comment: Remove the class off the div and just have <div id="PBScontent" style="display:none">. Then instead of $("#PBScontent").slideToggle do $("#PBScontent").show(); Does that work? If it does, slideToggle isn't doing what you want it to.

Comment: I feel as though the only remaining possibility is that you have some sort of fixed or static positioned element that is preventing the rest of the document to move. If you are using the HTML5 doctype, the combination of all three of my suggestions should definitely work. Otherwise somewhere in your css you have set a position:absolute or something similar.

Comment: I am using HTML5 doctype, and i have no position: absolute in my code although i do have position:relative. what else can be causing this? @Adosi

Comment: I have added a fiddle if you would like to take a look @Adosi

Comment: I fixed it. This <div> element <div id="PBScontent" class="commenthidden"></div> had a </p> and </div> randomly inside it that was breaking everything. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G59nH/2/

Comment: yes thank you, but everything else goes a bit off now that has been taken away? @Adosi

Comment: Got it now, thanks. Just needed to move the </div> and </p> to a different place. Thanks again @Adosi

Comment: Is there a way i can add a close link at the bottom that will close the content again? instead of clicking read more again to close it? @Adosi